# I'm taking a domestic flight with one airline and then flying internationally with another one?

Tags: uk, international-travel, american-airlines

I will be flying from SJU to ORD through United. I have about 7 hours before I joing a group of people to fly out from ORD to London through American Airlines.  What do I have to do in regards to checking in, TSA, customs, etc.? I will fly with a Carry on

Comment: You'll almost certainly be checking in, etc at ORD for your AA flight to London in exactly the same way as the rest of the group you're joining.

Comment: Unless you leave the terminal, you do not have to make the TSA queue again, provided you are traveling with a carry-on only.  You can check-in online for the AA flight as well.  There is no Customs on outbound flights.

Comment: Is this a single ticket?